# How to extend Liferay's 6.1 Service Builder?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'd like to extend the Service Builder of Liferay with custom features, like generate portlet and persistence layer from a specific XSD.

I searched the Web and the sources of liferay, but I can't get a clou where to start, where are the sources. Does some documentation exist about the internal structure of the service builder?

Note: I do not ask about "How to use the service builder".

Comment: Hey.. code for creating persistence classes and model classes seems in java file `liferay-portal-src-6.1.20-ee-ga2\portal-impl\src\com\liferay\portal\tools\servicebuilder\ServiceBuilder.java` HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify ServiceBuilder directly, prepare for an upgrade nightmare - after all, it's a code generator that most likely will be changed by Liferay in future versions as well.

In general, "all" it does is process a few template files - those are either velocity or freemarker templates (can't remember) that you can find in the portal source. (yes, I know this is simplified, and the templates aren't that straightforward)

If you want to generate portlet UIs matching the database structure with classic CRUD functionality, please look at [www.xmlportletfactory.org](http://www.xmlportletfactory.org) - they have solved this problem already and they're starting at a structure similar to servicebuilder, but from their solution generate even service.xml, so that they're better decoupled from future changes by Liferay.

Neat side effect, they might already do what you want to do (or maybe you can contribute your additional functionality)

Comment: Hi, yes this is a good starting point. But the generated portlets doesn't work. I get the error "BeanLocator is null for servlet context example". I posted this error on the forums site http://www.xmlportletfactory.org/forum/-/message_boards/message/145826?p_p_auth=KZrJ3ZT9 but nobody seems to have this problem